# Animating text, when a page loads up with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to web development. I am trying to apply jQuery to my website, such that when the page loads up, the heading is animated. But for some reason I am not able to get it working. Here is the javascript code :

```
$(window).ready(function() {
        $("h1").animate({left:'250px'});
       });
```

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome! </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery_functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried document as a selector too.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `h1` may have a `static` *position*. You may need to set a CSS `relative` or `absolute` *position* to that element like

```
h1 {position: relative}
```

and this jQuery code will work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("h1").animate({
        left: 250
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rept4ovf/)**

Comment: Thanks for the swift response.How and where exactly should i do this ?

Comment: add the CSS `h1 {position: relative}` rule as in my answer ans see it working in the JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 1):

CSS left only works with absolutely positioned elements. If you add position:absolute to your H1 tag, it will work.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
        $("h1").animate({left:'250px'});
       });
```

```css
h1 { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello!</h1>
```

Comment: not only on `absolute` but `relative` too ... as long is not `static`, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm new myself but it appears your animate option is missing an argument.

$('img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');  is an example.  yours tells it how much to move, but you left off the how.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing

```
$("h1").animate({left:'250px'});
```

to

```
$("h1").animate({marginLeft:'250px'});
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe `$(doucment).ready()`
I think it will be work ))